# keeping android AutoCompleteTextView suggestions on back button pressed

Tags: android

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in my recyclerview and i want to keep suggestions after touching back button. can somebody help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Use savedInstanceState but, depends how long time you need keep data? And what you gona do with data later?...Do you know Sharedpreference?

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}
...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

//Save the fragment's state here



}
```

Comment: no i meant that when keyboard is open and i have suggestions on screen. i want to first close keyboard then the suggestions.